# Sidekiq: how to pass a queue as a variable into a worker

Tags: sidekiq

I have a worker like so:

```
class MassDispatchServiceWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :bulk

  def perform(message_params)
    DispatchService.new(message_params).dispatch!
  end
end
```

However I have a need for the same exact method but to pass in a queue as a variable. Sometimes I want the queue to be bulk, other times I'll need something else. Is that possible with sidekiq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Sidekiq::Client` API.

```
Sidekiq::Client.push('class' => MassDispatchServiceWorker, 'args' => [], 'queue' => whatever)
```

Comment: That seems so ugly:( is that the only way to do it?

Comment: but what if i want a delayed job with a specific queue with a delay? Like this;
Sidekiq::Client.push({'class'=> 'SomeJob', 'delay_until'=> DateTime.tomorrow,  'args'=> [rec]})
didnt work.

Answer (score 10):

There is another way:

```
MyWorker.set(queue: 'foo').perform_async(1)
```

From https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2152#issuecomment-290376790